# Is it possible to get tensrflowp-gpu working on macbook pro with High Sierra

Tags: macos, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia, cudnn

I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu  on my macbook pro and have tried pretty much everything which I will briefly mention. But first here is my setup
Macbook pro retina 15"
High Sierra 10.13.4
NVIDIA GT650M card

Over the past two weeks I have  tried all sorts of combinations and fed up with drivers/versions especially with High Sierra 10.13.4 and variables and so on.

If anybody has had success with this please could they tell me or point me to the versions and method for 
CUDA
CUDNN
Tensorflow-gpu (understand 1.1 is the highest for mac)
XCode (I have 9.2)

and anything else.

I have my anaconda environment working well for all of the machine learning stuff on CPU and consider using the GPU to be the next challenge.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60016869/6117565

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a link](https://metakermit.com/2017/compiling-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-a-macbook-pro/) that may help.

I have installed using the same guidelines and it's working for me on macbook pro with same configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that .  I'd like to confirm the OS X version you used was 10.13.4 High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to compile tensorflow 1.4.0 with GPU support for my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with GT 750M card under MacOS 10.12.6 with instructions from the following link:

http://paolino.me/tutorial/tensorflow/machine-learning/deep-learning/gpu/2017/11/18/installing-tensorflow-1.4.0-macos-cuda/

Comment: Thank you. So far I have installed CUDA/cudnn/xcode and got the devQuery bandwidth CUDA samples to work (yaaay!) - I am struggling with the bazel tensorflow bit. Thank you once again. Will keep updating when I make progress. I have cuda driver 396.64 cuda 9.2 cudnn v7.1. One question do I have to disable SIP every time I restart my MacBook?

Comment: "Compiling TensorFlow can be time-consuming, so it's worth trying a pre-built package first. I have uploaded the wheel files I built to Google Drive, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tvNVxbY9Bc2RRVK3wokxs0X88S-x04qr?usp=sharingso download the relevant file, activate the relevant Python environment, and

$ pip install /path/to/tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl # Python 3.6
$ pip install /path/to/tensorflow-1.6.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl # Python 2.7"

Comment: you don't need to disable SIP everytime, just one time

Comment: Thank you once again.Will try again. I spent a lot of time clearing out anaconda and reinstalling python 3 and used  [link](http://paolino.me/tutorial/tensorflow/machine-learning/deep-learning/gpu/2017/11/18/installing-tensorflow-1.4.0-macos-cuda/) and configured tensorflow and got to the bazel build which is where I stumbled. it kept saying the version was higher. And then I hit upon the workspace not available error. On the plus side my CUDA still works!  For the relevant python env do you mean Python 3? Can I use one of my machine learning envs which has Python 3.5? Thank you very much

Comment: you may need to upgrade or downgrade your bazel version. if you're installing from the instructions you linked, you should be using bazel 0.7.0. I couldn't get tensorflow 1.4 to build with higher bazel versions.